# Logstash can't find JRuby

Tags: logstash

I download it at https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash. And test it in CentOS 7.0. The JRE's version is `1.8.0_101`. When I run `./bin/logstash agent -f config/log4j_to_es.conf` it prints:

```
Unable to find JRuby.
If you are a user, this is a bug.
If you are a developer, please run 'rake bootstrap'. Running 'rake' requires the 'ruby' program be available.
```

I download the `TAR.GZ` package. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found something really interesting relating to this error, where we see the following error:
    Unable to find JRuby.

In short, it turned out for me that the TAR.GZ file was incompletely unpacked.

I had a .tar.gz file and used tar -xzf command to extract its contents into a filesystem directory. What was missing was the following directory:
    logstash-5.5.2/vendor/jruby

I then found out that my server's filesystem was out of space, hence only partial TAR.GZ extraction happened. When I cleared up the filesystem, and unpacked the logstash archive, everything works! Happy days!

Answer (score 0):

In a tarballed installation, jruby exists under the `vendor` folder. Make sure it exists.
The logstash command you're running is basically a shell script, which sources a lib file `bin/logstash.lib.sh`

Also, try running in debug mode:

```
export DEBUG=1
./bin/logstash --help
```

The likely culprit is:

- you've set JAVA_HOME, which means you're using the OS java.
- you've accidentally set the `USE_RUBY` environment variable

Comment: I run  `export JAVACMD=`which java`` and I print the `JAVA_HOME` `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin`. So it seems right. Then I print the USE_RUBY and get nothing.

Comment: Having checked the shell, I can't find `jruby` in vender. How can I fix it?